# Do the elements of a cyclic multiplicative subsemigroup of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ add up to a multiple of $m$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

When I am doing my study, I found that for arbitrary positive integer $a,m$. Let $\mathbf{S}=\{ a^{n} \bmod m : n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \}$. Obviously, $\mathbf{S}$ is a finite set. I have list some random examples, they all support that the sum of elements in a certain $\mathbf{S}$ is the multiple times of the relevant $m$.

I am a junior mathematics student, so I think my method is a little bit naive.

I attempt to prove this but I meet some difficulties. I am seeking for some help and advice.

## UPDATE 1:

There seems some counter example on this statement. However, these counter example seems have similar pattern, and this statement is likely to be true for the majority case. I am wondering if it is possible to make some limitation on $a,m$.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, sorry, it should be m, type error.

Comment: Counterexample: $a=2$, $m=8$, $S=\{\,2,4,8,0\,\}$, sum is $14$, not a multiple of $m$. But it's easy to prove, if $\gcd(a,m)=1$, just using a little Number Theory, first few chapters of any intro Number Theory textbook.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Surely you need some more assumptions; otherwise, just take $a\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, and then $S=\{1\}$.

Comment: @Arturo, yes, thanks. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: If $a$ is a primitive root of $m$ then $m\phi(m)/2 = \sum\limits_{k \in S} k $

Comment: Worse than I thought: $a=3$, $m=26$, $S=\{\,3,9,1\,\}$, sum is $13$.

Comment: Is it possible to add some limitation on a and m to make this statement be true?

Comment: @AudraJacot: You keep bringing up $p$. There is no $p$ in your statement.

Comment: Sorry type error. @ArturoMagidin.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible, but probably not what you want. As Ganeshie8 has noted, if $a$ is a primitive root modulo $m$, then the sum of elements of $k$ is half the product of $m$ and $\phi(m)$ (Euler’s phi); thus, if $\phi(m)$ is even, it will be a multiple of $m$. And $\phi(m)$ is even for any integer other than $m=1$ and $m=2$, so that will always occur. However, only prime powers and twice prime powers have primitive roots.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: You want technicalities, fine: there are some p’s, but there is no $p$.

Comment: But if a and m be large prime number, the statement seems to be true. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: @Arturo, a monoid has an identity element, right? Since OP has $n\in{\bf Z}^+$, which I interpret as $\{\,1,2,3,\dots\,\}$, $S$ will not contain $1$ if $\gcd(a,m)>1$, so I'm not sure editing "submonoid" into the title accurately reflects Audra's question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Ah, yes; when $m$ is not prime, you need not hit the identity. I will fix that to subsemigroup...

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume $\gcd(a,m)=1$. Let $r$ be the *order* of $a$ modulo $m$, that is, $a^r\equiv1\bmod m$, and $a^s\not\equiv1\bmod m$ for $1\le s<r$. Then $$S=\sum_0^{r-1}a^n={a^r-1\over a-1}$$ so the question is, when does $m$ divide $(a^r-1)/(a-1)$. This certainly happens if $\gcd(a-1,m)=1$, and that certainly happens if $m$ is prime and $a\ne1$. Situation appears more complicated if $\gcd(a-1,m)>1$.