# How to find the cardinality of the following set?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This post has similar condition and objects of [that post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332527/how-to-prove-the-following-modulus-arithmetic-statement) .

When I am doing my study, I found that for arbitrary positive integer $a,m$. Let $\mathbf{S}=\{ a^{n} \bmod m : n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \}$. Obviously, $\mathbf{S}$ is a finite set.

Is it possible to write an algebraic expression of the cardinality of $\mathbf{S}$ when $a,m$ are specified?

Comment: Even just for the special case [$a=2$, $m$ prime](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60441/the-multiplicative-order-of-2-modulo-primes), this is a difficult problem. I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that the answer is likely "no".

Comment: @Arthur, how about not limited to algebraic expression, the expression involves infinite series and integral is also OK.

Comment: @AudraJacot RSA cryptographic system depends on the fact that solving $a^x \equiv b\pmod m$ is hard. Given $a,b,m$ it is nearly impossible to find $x$ even with using all the super computers - you can choose $a,m,x$ such that it is impossible to find $x$ in aeons.

Comment: maybe $$(a^{\varphi(m)\over 2}-1)(a^{\varphi(m)\over 2}+1)\equiv 0\bmod m$$ will help